# gnuplot - nudge and format label "at end"

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

Let's say I have a script that in the end plots it all with

```
plot filename.".csv" u 2:3 every ::3 lc rgb "#A52A2A" title "8" at end w lp,\
                  "" u 2:3:4 every ::3 lc rgb "#A52A2A" notitle w errorbars,\
                  "" u 2:7 every ::3 lc rgb "#008B8B" title "16" at end w lp,\
                  "" u 2:7:8 every ::3 lc rgb "#008B8B" notitle w errorbars,\
                  "" u 2:11 every ::3 lc rgb "#9932CC" title "32" at end w lp,\
                  "" u 2:11:12 every ::3 lc rgb "#9932CC" notitle w errorbars,\
                  "" u 2:15 every ::3 lc rgb "#008000" title "48" at end w lp,\
                  "" u 2:15:16 every ::3 lc rgb "#008000" notitle w errorbars,\
                  "" u 2:19 every ::3 lc rgb "#FFD700" title "64" at end w lp,\
                  "" u 2:19:20 every ::3 lc rgb "#FFD700" notitle w errorbars
```

This will end up looking like

[image]

How can I move the labels farther away from the lines and colour them in the line colour?

Comment: Maybe add spaces before titles? Don't know about colors.

Comment: You could script a way to save the last point coordinates and then use `set label TITLE at X+dx,Y textcolor linetype IDX`, but I'm not sure it is worth it. Such a key will never be very legible for the example plot.

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces within the quotes, just before the number (e.g. " 8") or use sprintf:

```
title sprintf("  %s","8")
```